# PHP - is it possible to list only directories and using braces at the same time with glob?

Tags: php, design-patterns, directory, glob

I would like to (ideally) use GLOB_ONLYDIR and GLOB_BRACE at the same time, because I would like to do some pattern matching like I can do with files ala `*.{txt,php,doc,...,<whatever>}` but with directories.

However, all my attempts for now have been quite futile (even dared to try `GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_ONLYDIR` remembering my good ol' days of fopen and C with the O_ flags but, of course, no luck), including things like `glob(glob($path, GLOB_BRACE), GLOB_ONLYDIR);` and other similar failed attempts.

My intention is to count the number of directories from a given path, but I would like to (optionally) pass a matching pattern for counting specific ocurrences.

How can I do it with glob? (or... is there a better approach/alternative to what I'm trying to do?)

Comment: As for alternatives: If you're using PHP 5.3+ and don't mind a bit of verbosity, you could use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/class.recursivedirectoryiterator) with a [RecursiveFilterIterator](http://php.net/class.recursivefilteriterator) to filter results using code instead of globbing.  There's a use example in the RecursiveFilterIterator comments.

Comment: you sure `GLOB_BRACE | GLOB_ONLYDIR` isn't working for you? Because I believe you *can* use that syntax to specify multiple flags

Comment: @andbeyond it didn't worked :P

Answer (score 0):

You can try grabbing all directories and intersecting them with all brace matches, e.g.

```
array_intersect(glob($plain_path, GLOB_ONLYDIR), glob($brace_path, GLOB_BRACE))
```

You'll just have to implement some way to discover what `$plain_path` is if you're only given the brace-match string (unless your situation is static enough for it to only ever be one path).